# Java fonts fallback mechanism

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, awt, fallback

When using Open-Sans font it shows arabic unicodes not parseable. But java does the fallback and displays these arabic characters.

```
    File fontFile = new File(new URI("file:///C:/Open-Sans.ttf"));
    Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile);
    font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24f);

    if (font.canDisplayUpTo("\u0639\u0631\u0636\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0645\u064a\u0644"
            + "\u0627\u0644\u0627\u0641\u062a\u0631\u0627\u0636\u064a") == -1) {
        System.out.println("arabic unicode parseable");
    }
    Frame f = new Frame();
    f.setFont(font);
    f.setBounds(50, 50, 400, 400);
    Label l = new Label("\u0639\u0631\u0636\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0645\u064a\u0644"
            + "\u0627\u0644\u0627\u0641\u062a\u0631\u0627\u0636\u064a");
    f.add(l);
    f.setVisible(true);
```

Output:
[image]
How is java actually processing this fallback, which font it is using to display these characters. In *java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\fontconfig.properties*:

```
sequence.fallback= lucida,\

                  chinese-ms950,chinese-hkscs,chinese-ms936,chinese-gb18030,\
                  japanese,korean,chinese-ms950-extb,chinese-ms936-extb
```

I tried by setting empty fallback,

```
sequence.fallback=
```

But still, the arabic characters get displayed. Hence, this fallback set in fontconfig.properties is doing nothing. I tried to debug the java source, *java.awt.Font* and *java.awt.Component* but didn't find where/how this fallback is happening.